# JQuery Selector With Some Conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JQuery selector with multiple conditions Email Validation**
 hi i have to validate Email address.
my following code works fine:

```
contact_email = $('#contact_email').val();
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
   //if Email address is empty it allowed but if it have any value then check whether proper email address or not
if(contact_email && !reg.test(contact_email)) {
        err += 1;
        $('#contact_email').addClass('boxerror');
    }
```

it works but following code not work

```
contact_email = $('#contact_email').val().is(reg.test(this.val())).addClass('boxerror');
```

**1.what mistake i had done?**

**2.JQuery with selector with multiple condition is possible**

Comment: jquery selector with condition is possiable?

Comment: i don't think we can test regex with `.is()` in jquery..read docs carefully.. http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: how i do it if the element is not valid then addclass() else removeclass() with in same line

Comment: use shorthand ifelse case as shown (contact_email && !reg.test(contact_email) ? $('#contact_email').addClass('boxerror') : $('#contact_email').removeClass('boxerror'))

Comment: by using ternary operator is good but i need to check on jquery assignments

Comment: I don't think you're asking the right thing here. Your question has nothing related to jQuery selectors.

Comment: `$('#contact_email').toggleClass('boxerror', !reg.test($('#contact_email').val()));` http://jsfiddle.net/8vqtaga3/1/

Comment: @SakthiKarthik Mistakenly added `$list` variable in my answer. Now I editted it. Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `.is(...)` works. You have to pass a jquery selector in `is()` function, or you can also pass a function which will be called by jquery for all the function. And it will return a boolean value.

To accomplish your task you will be needed to use `filter(...)`.

Here is the code to help you :

```
$("#contact_email").filter(function(index, element) {
    return !reg.test(element.value);
}).addClass("boxerror");
```

Full documentation for `filter()` is [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

**Hence :**

1. Mistake: you were using `is()` in wrong situation.
2. selector with multiple condition is possible if implemented jquery nicely.